# Detected dubious ownership in repository GITLAB CI/CD

Tags: docker, image, gitlab, cicd

I am facing this issue during try to deploy script with gitlab ci/cd:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/builds/Tri.BuiV/test-gitlab-cicd/.git/
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'C:/builds/Tri.BuiV/test-gitlab-cicd'
'C:/builds/Tri.BuiV/test-gitlab-cicd' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-83-1-1989435290-1148643240-1709935003-3943614564'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-93-2-1'
To add an exception for this directory, call:
    git config --global --add safe.directory C:/builds/Tri.BuiV/test-gitlab-cicd
```

I tried:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/builds/Tri.BuiV/test-gitlab-cicd
```

But the same error, why?

[image]

I tried:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/builds/Tri.BuiV/test-gitlab-cicd
```

But get the same issue.

Answer (score 10):

A great workaround has been posted on the GitLab forums [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29022#note_1356788508). It's to add the following git related environment variables to the *config.toml* of the affected runner:

```
[[runners]]
  environment = ["GIT_CONFIG_COUNT=1", "GIT_CONFIG_KEY_0=safe.directory", "GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_0=*"]
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Seems to be the most consistent solution. Had issue with submodules and kas, only able to fix that through this solution.

Comment: Agree with @Paiusco - as this solution doesn't require actual change of any file/configuration. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

If the error persists, it probably means your `git config --global` (which impacts `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`) does not use the same account as the one running your GitLab CI/CD.

If GitLab runs with a different account, it might try to access a folder initially created by you.
The GitLab pipeline itself would need to include:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory $CI_PROJECT_DIR
```

This I what is being automatically added for GitLab 15.8 in [MR 3538](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/merge_requests/3538).

---

The [solstice333](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630028/solstice333) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75143714/detected-dubious-ownership-in-repository-gitlab-ci-cd/75143862?noredirect=1#comment134110038_75143862) to [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 29022](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29022#note_1353878800), where [Kevin Navero](https://gitlab.com/knavero) explains:

> I found a workaround for my case.
>
> To clarify my environment a bit more, I'm using docker-windows executors/runners with powershell on windows-server.
> Forget what I mentioned earlier about suspecting `git config` being run under a different container than `git clone`/`fetch`. I do not believe that is accurate anymore.
>
> Gitlab-runner 14.10.1 works for me, so I rolled back to that.
>
> As a result, somehow the "dubious owner" error is pushed to a later point in runtime, within the main `.gitlab-ci.yml` build script.
> This allows me to do `git config --global --add safe.directory ...` in the `pre_build_script`, as opposed to any of the other `pre_*` scripts. I have no idea where or what containers the other `pre_*` scripts run in.
>
> AFAIK, this version of `gitlab-runner` does not support the `--docker-isolation` argument nor does it recognize `runners[i].docker.isolation = "hyperv"`.
> The alternative solution to achieve this is to edit the docker daemon json configuration, located in either `%userprofile%\.docker\windows-daemon.json` or `%programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json`.
> The entry to add is "`exec-opts":["isolation=hyperv"]`.
> `isolation=hyperv` is needed to provision CPUs and memory. Request to provision CPUs and memory is ignored otherwise (in process isolation).
> Of course, without provisioning a subset of resources per docker-windows executor, the concern is that multiple docker containers can be spawned on a single host, with too many processes that overwhelm the host with excessive context-switching.
>
> In `config.toml`, I added the following:
>
> ```
> [[runners]]
>   ...
>   pre_build_script = """
> $CI_PROJECT_POSIX_PATH = python -c "from pathlib import Path; >print(Path(r'$CI_PROJECT_DIR').resolve().as_posix())"
> echo "> git config --global --add safe.directory >$CI_PROJECT_POSIX_PATH"
> git config --global --add safe.directory $CI_PROJECT_POSIX_PATH
> """
>   ...
> ```
>
> Python3.11 is conveniently baked into the docker image that's specified in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` for the main build script to run in.`$CI_PROJECT_DIR` is something like `c:\builds\nextest-eng\usa\magnum`, all in lowercase.
> The "dubious owner" error message from Git suggests doing `git config --global --add safe.directory C:/builds/nextest-eng/usa/magnum`, and it turns out that this is case-sensitive, even on Windows (I am dumb for overlooking this since git-for-windows is case-sensitive for tracked paths).
>
> Python is used to automate the mapping of `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` to the exact case-sensitive path, with posix separators, that git-config suggests to use.
> In this is example, `$CI_PROJECT_POSIX_PATH` results in `C:/builds/nextest-eng/usa/magnum`.
> For hours, I was setting `c:/builds/nextest-eng/usa/magnum` as my `safe.directory` which was being ignored as a non-matching dirpath b.c. the drive letter was incorrectly lowercase.
>
> This might work for gitlab-runner 15.10 with the non-deprecated `pre_get_sources_script` hook instead (or the deprecated `pre_clone_script`), but if it does not use the `.gitlab-ci.yml` specified image and uses the gitlab-runner-helper instead, then python will not be found and it will fail.
> In the interest of time and b.c. gitlab-runner 15.10 does not offer any additional gain that I need right now, I am going to stick with gitlab-runner 14.10.1.

Comment: Visiting that MR eventually led me into https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/368133#note_1032528491 which led me into details about putting the git-config in the `pre_build_script` discussed in https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section.

Comment: seems like I have to put it at the `pre_get_sources_script` actually...

Comment: hm, well, this did not work for me. I'm shook. I verified that the script is running in the build log prior to fetching the changes and reinit of an existing repo. The `git config --global --add safe.directory ...` command I'm running is equivalent to the one suggested by git in the fatal dubious owner error message. I verified my runner's config.toml once more. Could be that gitlab is transitioning from one docker container to another between running the hook and reinit of existing repo from a mounted volume. I give up. I am going to contact gitlab emergency support.

Comment: @solstice333 OK, don't hesitate to comment here when GitLab support will have answered something conclusive for you.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29022#note_1353878800

Comment: @solstice333 Thank you for your comment. I have included your reference in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had this as well when using an image from mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016 as the executor, but it turned out the reason it was failing was because I was pre-creating the builds folder in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir C:\builds\my_repo
WORKDIR C:\builds\my_repo
```

When I removed this from the Dockerfile, the git dubious ownership error went away.

(The reason I was creating this folder was because I was using the build container in local testing, and wanted the exact same path setup to be present, so I needed the folder locally too. In future I'll create it manually though.)

Comment: FYI I'm still getting the owenership error with a nanoserver build image. I note that the error in that case is appearing earlier in the build. I.e. the nanoserver build doesn't have the build folder pre-created, but fails at the first "Preparing the docker-windows executor" stage, while the servercore was failing at the later "Getting source from Git repository" stage. Will update if I manage to fix this...